# Can I tell IIS 8.5 to return a 404 when using httpErrors?

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5, custom-errors, integrated-pipeline-mode

I'm working on a (Web Forms) site running on IIS 8.5 and am currently setting up error handling for 404s and 500s.

I already have the `system.web` > `customErrors` setup, but since we're running in Integrated mode/newer version of IIS it's pulling from `system.webServer` > `httpErrors`.

Using the IIS GUI I opted to replace the standard IIS error pages with a static HTML file, on the site:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath=""
        path="/problem.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath=""
        path="/problem.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Unfortunately, while the correct error page is displayed, instead of a returning a 404 a 200 is returned, and a 302 followed by a 200 is returned for 500 errors.

For older versions of IIS, or those not running in Integrated mode, you could set `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` on the `customErrors` element and that would resolve this issue.

I've tried setting `existingResponse` on `httpErrors` to all three available options, as well as tried updating setting `responseMode="File"`, but these changed nothing.

Is there any way to do something similar for the [`httpErrrors` element](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)? Or am I stuck with pointing the errors to an ASP.NET page and returning the appropriate error from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this, you can set this configuration into the `<httpErrors>` in your WebConfig file. Like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/WebForms/Index.aspx" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
<system.webServer/>
```

The `responseMode=File` will preserve the original error code, and show the static page.

Comment: Looks like the combination of `existingResponse="Replace"` and `responseMode="File"` was the trick. However, for a static HTML I also had to drop the initial slash, `path="problem.html"` (otherwise it was returning a white page error). I also had to clear out the `customErrors` element (well, mode just set to `RemoteOnly`)

Comment: You can also use `defaultResponseMode="File"` on the `httpErrors` element to avoid declaring it on multiple `error` nodes